# WHAT HEADERS MUST I USE TO USE GOOGLE API

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-api

I Think that I need more headers for use Google Cloud Resource Manager API.
This is the process that I follow to authenticate and get permissons. But now the API  dont sends me explained error.

FIRST: Create a oAuth popup:

```js
openPopup() 
  {
    const name = 'Authorization'
    const options = `width=${ 500 },height=${ 600 },left=${ 0 },top=${ 0 }`;
    const url = `
          https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
          client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&
          response_type=code&
          include_granted_scopes=true&
          scope=https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&
          redirect_uri=http://localhost&
          access_type=offline`;

    return window.open(url, name, options);
  }
```

THEN Verify the code:

```js
authApi(): Observable<any>{

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })

    let body = `
        code=<RESPONSE_CODE>&
        client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&
        client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&
        grant_type=authorization_code&
        redirect_uri=http://localhost`;


    return this._http.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`,
    body, {headers: headers})
  }
```

BUT NOW, WHEN I TRY TO USE THE API sends me this error

```
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects: 0 Unknown Error"
```

I try to use the API with the next function

```js
createProject( token ): Observable<any>{


    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    })


    const body = {
      "name": 'newAgent',
      "projectId": 'newAgent123',
      "labels": {
        "test": 'test'
      }
    }


    return this._http.post(`https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects`,
      body, { headers: headers }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Double-check the return value from this line: `return this._http.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'`. The returned data is a JSON structure. You want to return the value of the key `token` after parsing.

Comment: Of course, and I don't pretend return the json response. Just when I use _createProject_ function (the last) I send the *access_token* property

Answer (score 1):

there are already [javascript library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/cloudresourcemanager/index.html) that handle all this for you in an easy way. it supports different ways of authentications also: **OAuth2, service to service and API key**. for oauth2 , which is your case it can be like:

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);
// a get request to this url that will send you back the code
const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
  access_type: 'offline',

  // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
  scope: [] // the needed list of scopes
});

// use the code to get the tokens
const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
```

now for resource manager api, you can check this [example here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create#examples_1)

Comment: Thanks but It don't works for me, because the problem is in the Resource Manager API don't send me response, I research and I found that the problem maybe is in the CORS. but I appreciate for showing me a way to make previous work cleaner